# Simple C program using If statement stops running in VS Code

Tags: c, if-statement, visual-studio-code

I made a simple C program to understand the working of the If-Else statement but in VS Code the program stops at second input without any error prompt. Please tell me what's the problem with my program? I'm a beginner in programming.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char math, sci;

    printf("Have you passed Mathematics test (y/n)\n");
    scanf("%c", &math);

    printf("Have you passed Science test (y/n)\n");
    scanf("%c", &sci);

    if ((math == 'y') && (sci == 'y'))
    {
        printf("You get a gift of worth Rs. 45.");
    }
    else if ((math == 'n') && (sci == 'y'))
    {
        printf("You get a gift of worth Rs. 15.");
    }
    else if ((math == 'y') && (sci == 'n'))
    {
        printf("You get a gift of worth Rs. 15.");
    }
    else if ((math == 'n') && (sci == 'n'))
    {
        printf("You don't get any gift.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just change

scanf("%c", &math) to scanf(" %c", &sci)

scanf("%c", &sci) to scanf(" %c", &math)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char math, sci;
    printf("Have you passed Mathematics test (y/n)\n");
    scanf(" %c", &math);
    printf("Have you passed Science test (y/n)\n");
    scanf(" %c", &sci);
    if ((math == 'y') && (sci == 'y'))
    {
         printf("You get a gift of worth Rs. 45.\n");
    }
    else if ((math == 'n') && (sci == 'y')||(math == 'y') && (sci == 'n'))
    {
         printf("You get a gift of worth Rs. 15.\n");
    }
    else if ((math == 'n') && (sci == 'n'))
    {
         printf("You don't get any gift.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second `scanf()` reads the newline that was left pending in `stdin` by the first `scanf()`.

Use `scanf(" %c", &sci);` with an initial space in the conversion string to consume any newlines and initial white space in the input. Also test the return value of `scanf()` to detect premature end of file.

Here is modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char math, sci;

    printf("Have you passed Mathematics test (y/n)\n");
    if (scanf(" %c", &math) != 1) {
        printf("Missing input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Have you passed Science test (y/n)\n");
    if (scanf(" %c", &sci) != 1) {
        printf("Missing input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if ((math == 'y') && (sci == 'y')) {
        printf("You get a gift of worth Rs. 45.\n");
    } else
    if ((math == 'n') && (sci == 'y')) {
        printf("You get a gift of worth Rs. 15.\n");
    } else
    if ((math == 'y') && (sci == 'n')) {
        printf("You get a gift of worth Rs. 15.\n");
    } else
    if ((math == 'n') && (sci == 'n')) {
        printf("You don't get any gift.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```